# I need some advice about correct positioning and display CSS please

Tags: html, css, css-position

My first time here.  Kinda nervous, so i'll get straight into it.

I'm currently studying CSS, and have worked through a lot of different examples of positioning and display on a variety of different websites.

So, in order to practice and give myself some kind of goal, I created a "hacker themed" webpage, with very basic navigation bars.

It took me so long to footer about and get things in place, and i'm pretty sure i've messed a lot up, or used things i didn't have to.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html> 
  <head> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title> Hacker Games Directory </title> 
  </head> 

<body>
<!--EDIT THESE LINKS TO LEAD TO DIFFERENT CONTENT PAGES. 
THIS CAN BE CONSIDERED THE WEB PAGE NAVIGATION BAR UNTIL I LEARN BETTER. -->

<div id="navbar">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="home.html">Home </a></li> 
        <li><a href="about.html"> About</a> </li> 
        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact Us</a></li> 
        <li><a href="links.html"> Links </a></li> 
        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li> 
        <li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li> 
    </ul>
 </div>


<!--THIS DIV CAN MOVE THE PAGE HEADING AND INTRO SLOGAN AROUND.  WILL CHANGE EVENTUALLY FOR A GRAPHIC IMAGE -->
<div class="sitelogo">
    <div class="container">
        <h1> Hacker Games Directory</h1> 
            <p> Find the latest info about hacker games here! </p> 
    </div>  
</div>


<!--SideBar for Navigation to Games -->         
<div class="sidebar"> 
    <div class="sidelinks">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.hackerexperience.com" target="_blank">Hacker Experience </a></li> 
            <li><a href="https://www.hackerexperience.com">Hacker Experience 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.indiedb.com/hacknet"> HackNet </a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://www.hacker-project.com">Hacker-Project </a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://www.slavehack.com">SlaveHack </a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://www.introversion.com">Uplink </a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://www.hackerforever.com">Hacker Forever </a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://www.secretrepublic.net">Secret Republic </a></li> 
            <li><a href="https://www.codelinkv2.com">CodeLink V2 </a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://www.streethacker.com">Street Hacker </a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div> 
</div> 


<!--CONTAINS THE CONTENT IN THE CENTRE OF THE PAGE, NOT INCLUDING THE TITLE AND PARAGRAPH BELOW THE NAVBAR -->
<div class="centrestuff"> 
    <h3>Hacker Games Directory</h3>
    <p>Thank you for visiting my webpage.  This is a site dedicated to the truly addictive PC games which are hacker themed. </p>
    <p>Although they are little known, they can take away hours of your day </p> 
    <p>Use the bar on the side to have a look through what <em> I believe </em> are the best hacker games currently active. </p> 
    <p>The bar along the top leads to reviews, videos, guides and contacts.  If you believe I have missed something out, or misjudged a game i've mentioned, please feel free to leave a message and let me know. </p>  
</div> 

</body>  
</html>
```

And here is the related CSS:

```
/* Cascading StyleSheet for my Hacker Themed Webpage. 
I'm probably mixing up which positioning value to use where, and i've probably mixed the wrong types all over the place. 
I'm happy that I got the page sitting "roughly" the way I want, but I know I can improve this A LOT 
Created 8/21/2015 and linked to index.html. */

body {
  background-color:black;
} /* background may be changed at later date for an image file */

#navbar { /* styles and positions the navigation bar bordering etc */
  position:fixed;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-top:-20px; 
  margin-bottom:50px;
  margin-left:110px;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline;
}

#navbar li {  /* edit this to increase space between navbar buttons, and their margins*/
  width:100px;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:30px;
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
}

a {  /* changes the appearance of the links themselves within the navbar*/
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:Cursive;
  color:lime;
  background-color:black;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-color:red;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:2px;
  margin-right:5px;  
}

a:hover {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
  background-color:blue;
}

.sidebar {
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-50px;
  margin-top:50px;
  display:block;
  height:500px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding-top:5px;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  text-align:centert;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:Cursive;
  color:lime;
  background-color:black;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-color:red;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:2px;   
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
  background-color:blue;
}

.sidelinks li {         /* ADDING THIS ALLOWED ME TO CHANGE THE LIST STYLE, WHICH I HAD TROUBLE WITH REMOVING UL DOTS FROM MY BAR */
  padding-top:5px;
  list-style-type:none;
}

.sitelogo {
  font-family:Cursive;
  font-size:24px;
  color:lime;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:210px;
  margin-top:50x;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}

.container p {      /* lets me individually manage the intro/slogan below the page heading.  */
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:25px;
  margin-left:-15px;
  color:blue;
}


/*This is used to place the content in the middle of the page.  It feels very clunky and messy at the moment so i want to try to learn page layouts with CSS better.  Positioning and display is where i mess up. If i get the hang of that, i can create a distinctive looking content area. */
.centrestuff  {         
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:240px;
  margin-top:200px;
  color:red; 
}
```

Thank you for your time and any answers.  Hopefully this topic will become a little clearer to me.

Comment: Oh wow.  i forgot to include what it looks like.  It's not too far off what my aim already was, but i feel i went a very long and convoluted way about it.   http://i.imgur.com/ERRXLql.png

Comment: You also never asked a question lol

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: sorry, i thought the comment implied the question lol. It's more of a generic question than specific.  Where in CSS am i overusing positioning and display elements or using them incorrectly, and how can i improve upon what is obvious (even to my relative newness) a very messy job?

Comment: One suggestion i have, is to use :focus {outline:none;} if you plan on using border radius on any buttons or input.

Comment: And "what is the question"? Seeing none, I've voted to close this as opinion-based (eg. layout, looks, style).

Comment: wow, unforgiving much.  never mind.  close it, i'll close my account.  thanks for looking anyway .

Comment: @user5253800 Keep in mind that the question being downvoted/closed doesn't reflect on your character as a person, it just means that this specific question isn't a great fit for Stack Overflow. Sorry your first experience with Stack Overflow was getting a question closed and a negative comment, but I promise that if you decide to come back, there are people here that take more of a nurturing/teaching angle and less of a snarky/cynical angle towards new users, and we will help you get familiar with what's on and off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the jungle!

I took quick peek at your code even tho I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but great start there!

Since you've only asked for advices, I will gladly save you some precious time. I wish I knew all these tricks when I first started designing websites years ago, but oh well we learn with our mistakes.

First thing first, Stack Overflow prefers specific questions to general questions. If your questions are too wide, they are most likely to be down voted and closed.

I suggest you take more time to read the rules before posting your future posts. It will save you lots of frustration ;)

With that being said, I can state few tricks here and there, but my answer is just a little helper and is definitely not exclusive!

With that being said...

When designing websites, you should always keep **responsive design** in mind.

There are several ways that can be used to design responsively:

- With the use of frameworks such as JQuery Mobile, bootstrap, RWD Retrofit, [etc];
- By doing it [yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) with the proper use of `min-width` `width` `min-height` `padding` `margin` and of course with the use of [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp); (which is my personal favorite since it allows you more flexibility).

Use percentage for measuring instead of pixels. The reason for this, you've guessed it, is adaptivity and flexibility. Also, it is important that you give the proper names to your `divs` and follow a logical design pattern such as header, main_container and footer. This is just regular stuff that will save you headaches trying to debug spaghetti code.

In its most primitive form, responsive design is basically setting `min-width` and playing around with `padding` and `margin` so that your design adjusts and adapts to any screen.

With a bit of research on Google and W3 schools, it should get you started just fine!

If you need more help getting started, you can play around with something very basic that I did. It is fully responsive:

```css
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:220px;
    min-height:320px;
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin:auto 0;
}


/*Using parents div to better control the responsive pattern 
you can put everything inside of a block and it will take charge of getting everything responsive. Dont bring any change to the block. It will automatically take the size and the shape of its child.*/

.block{
    display:block;
    min-width:240px;
    width:auto;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    padding:1%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    background:whitesmoke; 
}

#header_container{
    min-width:240px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:auto 0;
    background:whitesmoke;
}

.headerfix:after {
     display: block;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     }
     
.headerfix { 
    border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9;
    background:white;
    display: block; 
    position:fixed; 
    min-width:240px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:99;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto 0;
}

#top_header{
    padding:1%;
}


#horizontal_menu{
float:right;
}


.main_container{
    width:85%;
    height:auto;
    
}

.maincontainerfix:after {
     display: block;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     }
     
.maincontainerfix { 
    display: block;
    min-width:240px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    width:85%;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
    padding-bottom:1%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:15%;
    margin-left:6.5%;
    margin-right:6.5%;
    
}

.welcome_msg{
    text-align:justify;
}

#footer_container{
    min-width:240px;
    width:100%;
    background:whitesmoke;
}

#footer{
    text-align:center;
    padding:1%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    
        <div id="header_container"  class="headerfix">
            <div id="top_header">
                
                
               <span> im the logo</span>
                
 
                <div id="horizontal_menu">
<a href="home.html">Home </a>
<a href="about.html"> About</a> 
<a href="contact.html"> Contact Us</a>
<a href="links.html"> Links </a>
<a href="videos.html">Videos</a> 
<a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a> 
                </div>
                    
            </div>
        
       

        </div>
    
    
    <div class="main_container maincontainerfix">
    
        
        <div class="block">
            
            <div class="vertical_sidebar">
                
                <ul id="vertical_menu">
            
                    <li class="vertical-menu-link">
                        
                        <a href="https://www.hackerexperience.com" target="_blank">Hacker Experience </a></li> 
            <li class="vertical-menu-link"><a href="https://www.hackerexperience.com">Hacker Experience 2 </a></li>
            <li class="vertical-menu-link"><a href="https://www.indiedb.com/hacknet"> HackNet </a></li> 
            <li class="vertical-menu-link"><a href="http://www.hacker-project.com">Hacker-Project </a></li> 
            <li class="vertical-menu-link"><a href="http://www.slavehack.com">SlaveHack </a></li> 
            <li class="vertical-menu-link"><a href="http://www.introversion.com">Uplink </a></li> 
            <li class="vertical-menu-link"><a href="http://www.hackerforever.com">Hacker Forever </a></li> 
            <li class="vertical-menu-link"><a href="http://www.secretrepublic.net">Secret Republic </a></li> 
            <li class="vertical-menu-link"><a href="https://www.codelinkv2.com">CodeLink V2 </a></li> 
            <li class="vertical-menu-link"><a href="http://www.streethacker.com">Street Hacker </a></li>
        </ul> 
            
            </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
        
        
        <div class="centrestuff"> 
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            
            <div class="welcome_msg">
    Thank you for visiting my webpage!<br><br>

There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
            
            <br><br>
                
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </div>
</div> 
        
        
    
    
    
    
    <div class="block">
        Put something inside
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="block">
        Put something inside
    </div>
        
        <div class="block">
         Put something inside
    </div>
        
        
        
        <div class="block">
         Put something inside
    </div>
        
        
        <div class="block">
         Put something inside
    </div>
        
        <div class="block">
         Put something inside
    </div>
    
        </div>
    
    
   
    
    
       <div id="footer_container">

      <div id="footer">  
        
        All Rights Reserved © Lorem Ipsum 2015
      </div>
    
    
</div>

    
    
    
    
</body>
```

Hope it helps!